# Python schedule a function to run every 10 seconds using Sched

Tags: python, scheduler

I want to have a function run every 10 seconds. The script is scheduled on Airflow to run between 9 am to 11 am.

If the condition is met, the process schedule will stop. However, it seems the function only ran once. Can anyone help let me know what I should modify to make it work?

```
'''
import pandas as pd
import sched, time
import datetime
import smtplib
import io
'''

'''
def timedTask():
    scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    scheduler.enter(10, 1, task)
    scheduler.run()
'''

'''
def task():
    dq_value = % sql
    if dq_value > 1:
        return 
    else: 
        print("wait")

'''

'''
timedTask()
'''
```